# How can I configure Spring to use Json4s to serialize response bodies?

Tags: spring, scala, jackson, json4s

I'm using Spring Boot in a Scala project, and I already use Json4s for serializing & deserializing JSON. Up until now, I've been writing endpoints like this:

```scala
@RequestMapping(path = Array("/getSomething"), produces = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
def getSomething: String = {
  // do some things
  val resultValue: ResultType = ??? // where ResultType is some case class that can be serialized with json4s
  json4s.native.Serialization.write(resultValue)
}
```

However, I'd really like to be able to avoid that last step while making it clearer what the return type of the endpoint is. Further, I'd like to be able to extract the return type in order to generate API docs. So instead, I'd like to write the same thing like this:

```scala
@RequestMapping(path = Array("/getSomething"), produces = Array(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
def getSomething: ResultType = {
  // do some things
  resultValue
}
```

When I do this, however, the result is always just `{}`. I assume this is because Jackson is used by Spring instead of Json4s and I don't have the case classes annotated for use with Jackson. All I want to do is add some interceptor that is called on every endpoint and transforms the result into a JSON string. Writing the interceptor is easy (it would just be `json4s.native.Serialization.write`), but how can I register it in order to get Spring to use it automatically every time?

Comment: BEWARE: Json4s is [vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial)!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `json4s-jackson` module and register your case class with a custom Serializer by creating a Spring Bean like:

```scala
  @Bean def json4sCustomizer: Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer = builder => {
    builder.serializerByType(classOf[ResultType], new JsonSerializer[ResultType] {
      val json4sSerializer = new json4s.jackson.JValueSerializer
      implicit val formats:Formats = DefaultFormats

      override def serialize(value: ResultType, gen: JsonGenerator, serializers: SerializerProvider): Unit =
        json4sSerializer.serialize(json4s.Extraction.decompose(value), gen, serializers)
    })
  }
```

To replace Jackson entirely would involve [HTTP Message Converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.4.RELEASE/api//org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/http/HttpMessageConverters.html) and may be more/less convenient, depending on other concerns of your app

```
  @Bean def json4sConverter: HttpMessageConverter[AnyRef] = new AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter {
    override def readInternal(resolvedType: Type, reader: Reader): AnyRef = ???
    override def writeInternal(value: Any, typ: Type, writer: Writer): Unit = ???
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Could you provide more details on using message converters? I see `AbstractJsonHttpMessageConverter` but I'm not sure how to create and register it in a way that it would be used for every return type (`AnyRef`). I feel like the message converter way is more applicable to my use case since I want to use this for every endpoint.

Comment: The Serializer approach will work for every endpoint that uses the registered type.

If you have multiple case classes, you could register it with a common trait, even `scala.Product`